# Unable to see some pages after laravel deployed into shared hosting

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, routes, laravel-5.8

Successfully deployed my laravel application in shared hosting.
Well some pages also I can see in server.
But unable to see some pages in server, but can see on local host.

I have tried many solutions available .. but could not able to fix it.
domain.com/admin/home can be viewed on server.
but domain.com/admin/postjob has 500 error on server, but working fine in local host.

Laravel folder is copied under root and the contents of laravel/public is copied to public_html/

Lets first check routes.

```
//Admins Index Page
Route::get('/admin/home', 'admin\AdmhomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
//Job Posting by Admin - View
Route::get('/admin/postjob', 'JobsController@pjbyadm')->name('admin.postjob');
```

Lets see Controller - JobsController

```
//Post Job by Admin 
public function pjbyadm(Request $request){
$auth = Auth::guard('admin');
if ($auth->check()){
//return view('admin.CRjob_ajob'); tried this first
return \view('admin.CRjob_ajob');
}
else {
return redirect('/mikeadmin');
}
```

Folder structure for views
Resources --> admin --> CRjob_ajob

.htaccess file in public_html folder looks like following.

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

server php file has

```
//require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
require_once __DIR__.'../public_html/index.php';
```

Using laravel 5.8 version.

Expected to see the page admin/postjob, which is working fine in local host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `php artisan cache:clear` before uploading to server then re upload or another solution is add this to your route

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return "Cache cleared";
});
```

then call domain.com/clear-cache

Comment: Yeah Matius, I did tried that. but still I am facing the same problem.
In the Jobs Controller, I have kept message to display before return view and successfully got executed, which shows that problem might be in that return statement.

If we think that there is a problem in the blade, its working fine in local host.

If we just think if we need anything else on server let me know. Its strange. domain.com/admin/home is executing fine, but domain.com/admin/postjob. 

I thought there might be a problem with naming conventions so I changed from admin.CRjob-ajob to admin.CRjob_ajob.

Comment: can you post your blade view? or can you turn debug mode to on so you can inspect the problem easier

Comment: <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.postjob') }}" title="Post Requirements">Post Jobs</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.valljobs') }}" title="View all posted Jobs">View Jobs</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="services.html" title="Update posted jobs">Update Jobs</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="candidates_list.html" title="Archieve Jobs">Archive Jobs</a>
        </div>

Comment: Thanks for the debug mode suggestion, I enabled it and I found there is a problem in alphabets case mismatch. So I corrected and happy to say thanks to you.